# How to only change the range of yaxis for the second plot in px.bar and focet_row has a value?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have this code below, and I want to change only the yaxis range of the second plot. the problem is that all yaxes' ranges changed:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()

fig = px.bar(df, x="sex", y="total_bill", facet_row="day", barmode="group")

fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 60], row=1, col=1)

fig.show()
```

I tried multiple solutions with `fig.for_each_yaxis()` and `fig.layout["yaxis2"].update(range=[0,10])` but no solution works.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graph layout information, there is a setting for which y-axis criteria should be adjusted to which y-axis, and this is accomplished by disabling it. I was made aware of this feature by your question.+1

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()

fig = px.bar(df, x="sex", y="total_bill", facet_row="day", barmode="group")


fig.layout["yaxis2"].update(range=[0,10], autorange=False, matches=None)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't need to write this line `fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 60], row=1, col=1)`

Comment: Assuming the code in the question, I have added the code. If it is not needed, I will remove it and update the image, but what do you want me to do? Do you want to remove the code in your question?

Comment: This was my attempt to solve the problem but it didn't work. You can use your own solution :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Put a follow-up question, how can I only change the first y-axis indexed by 0? I used fig.layout["yaxis"] but again all y-axes changed. I really do not understand how it works.

Comment: It is possible to do so by stopping the interlocking of the y-axis of each of them. `fig.layout["yaxis"].update(range=[50,500], autorange=False, matches=None);fig.layout["yaxis3"].update(matches=None);fig.layout["yaxis4"].update(matches=None)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I used `fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)` to control each y-axis separately.